# TYPO3 form - Editing of form.yaml files not possible in the backend

Tags: forms, yaml, typo3, typo3-8.x

I need to edit the configuration files of the TYPO3 form extension on the webserver. As I have no access via FTP I need to edit the files in the TYPO3 backend. The problem is, I am not allowed to edit files with the extension .form.yaml.
In the install tool I added
[SYS][textfile_ext] = txt,html,htm,css,inc,php,php3,tmpl,js,sql,yaml,form.yaml,form
Now I can edit files with the extension yaml but no files with the extension form.yaml

Is there another configuration option I have to set to be able to edit the form.yaml files?
Is it possible to change the standard extension of my configuration files from .form.yaml to .yaml?
I am using TYPO3 8.7.30 and form 8.7.30.

Comment: where do you need a file with the file extension `form.yaml`? in the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/8.7/en-us/Concepts/Configuration/Index.html#yaml-registration) you can have different names and simple file-extension `.yaml`

Comment: The forms can only be created with the backend module. Forms created by this module are stored with the file extension .form.yaml. Where can I change this default format?

Comment: either you use (and configure) your own files using only `.yaml`  or you use the appropriate BE module which only uses the extension `.form.yaml` to avoid tampering with this file which might result in a broken file (and broken form in the FE). If anyone does not trust you to have FTP, he would not trust you to build clean forms (without BE-wizard), either he grants you FTP, or he has to do necessary changes to the forms himself.

Comment: This does not work. The custom forms with the extension .yaml are not selectable. I followed the tutorial on this page: https://jweiland.net/typo3/beispiele-anleitungen-faq/typoscript/ext-form-speicherort-der-formulare-festlegen.html

Comment: How can I select a form which is defined in a yaml-file in the form content element? The content element only shows forms which are defined in a fom.yaml-configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bernd already said, since TYPO3 8 editing of `.form.yaml` files is not allowed in the backend for security reasons.
I wanted the editing to allow backend users the definition of different upload folders.
But different upload folders can also be defined in the central `.yaml`configuration file ([TYPO3 8 form - Define several file upload folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64935200/typo3-8-form-define-several-file-upload-folders)).

So there is no need to enable editing of `.form.yaml` files for backend users.